# differential operator of composition functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I got confused about the following derivative: $$d(df\circ g)(p)h(p)= d^2f(p)(h(p),g(p))+df(p)\,dg(p)h(p)$$ I can't see the relation between the left and right hand sides!

Comment: I am irritated by the comma in one term of the right side...

Comment: i found like that in the book .. what do you suggest?